# PHP Woes - 500 Internal Server Error (brand new server)

Tags: php, centos5, 500-error

Anyone ever seen these errors, or something like it?

```
/usr/bin/php: error while loading shared libraries: libcom_err.so.2: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory

[warn] UID of script "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/index.PHP" is smaller than min_uid

[info] Executing "/home/mysite/public_html/index.php" as UID 501, GID 501
```

I am really not sure what the fix is to that, but I assume I have some memory settings in WHM/Cpanel set poorly?

--- UPDATE:

Using the command as stated in the answer below, here is what I see when loading my user's index page (I've masked IP and username of my server):

```
==> /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log <==
[Sat Apr 23 17:37:18 2011] [error] [client IPADDRESS] /usr/bin/php: error while loading shared libraries: libcom_err.so.2: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
[Sat Apr 23 17:37:18 2011] [error] [client IPADDRESS] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Sat Apr 23 17:37:18 2011] [error] [client IPADDRESS] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/500.shtml

==> /usr/local/apache/logs/suphp_log <==
[Sat Apr 23 17:37:18 2011] [info] Executing "/home/username/public_html/index.php" as UID 501, GID 501
```

Further, when I go directly to my IP address (with which I've just put a simple PHP Redirect to my domain name inside of the index.php...) these are the errors i get:

```
==> /usr/local/apache/logs/access_log <==
IPADDRESS - - [23/Apr/2011:17:40:58 -0400] "GET /index.PHP HTTP/1.1" 404 -

==> /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log <==
[Sat Apr 23 17:40:58 2011] [error] [client IPADDRESS] SoftException in Application.cpp:357: UID of script "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/index.PHP" is smaller than min_uid
[Sat Apr 23 17:40:58 2011] [error] [client IPADDRESS] Premature end of script headers: index.PHP
[Sat Apr 23 17:40:58 2011] [error] [client IPADDRESS] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/500.shtml

==> /usr/local/apache/logs/suphp_log <==
[Sat Apr 23 17:40:58 2011] [warn] UID of script "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/index.PHP" is smaller than min_uid
```

Finally...
These are empty:

- modsec_audit.log
- modsec_debug_log

and I see in suexec.log:

```
: uid: (501/username) gid: (501/username) cmd: redirect.cgi
```

and more of the same errors as already stated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for an answer for this and figured this one out:

Set the ownership of the file to nobody. That is

> chown nobody:nobody index.php

Now I'm not getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you might be running a Cpanel server with Suphp. From the error this seems to be permission/ownership issue, indicating that the owner of the PHP file is called incorrect, or the permissions are higher than that allowed in suphp.conf.

You can check the logs for further details of the error:

```
tail -fvn0 /usr/local/apache/logs/*log
```

Comment: @Caleb and @ajo, please see above for updates. Thanks...